# Changing Firefox proxy settings?

Tags: .net, firefox, vbscript, proxy

How can I change Firefox's proxy settings from a script like a vb script or maybe .net? If someone could show me how to do this it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing to the `prefs.js` file, however, my understanding is that this file is only loaded on startup, and Firefox might overwrite your changes when shutting down so I think the only safe way of doing this would be to:

1. Shut down all Firefox processes.
2. Change `prefs.js`.
3. Start up Firefox.

This Code project article should show you how to close down a process from vbscript: [DestroyWindow in VBScript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/gopal_code.aspx)

You can use the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28VS.85%29.aspx) to read/write to files.

I think something like this would work for starting it up again:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run Chr(34) & "PathToFireFox.exe" & Chr(34), 1, false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*This program will find the path to application data of user,and get the path 
(\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default) and find proxy from the file prefs.js  */


#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <winerror.h>
#include <vector>

#define MAX 8192
using namespace std;

wstring ReadProxyFromFile(wstring fileName);
wstring ParseAndGetProxyDetails (wstring strLine, wstring field);
wstring ReadINIFileAndGetFirefoxProfilePath( wstring &profileFilePath );

/// 
/// This function converts wstring to string.
/// 
string ToString(wchar_t const * pwch, UINT code_page)
{
  // Allocate the appropriate space
  int sizeRequired = WideCharToMultiByte( code_page, 0, pwch, -1, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL);
  char * ach = new char[sizeRequired + 1];

  // Convert it
  WideCharToMultiByte( code_page, 0, pwch, -1, ach, sizeRequired, NULL, NULL);

  // Put it into the return value
  string ret(ach);

  // Clean up
  delete[] ach;

  // Return the new string
  return ret;
}

/// 
/// This function splits a string into fields using a separator.
/// 

vector<string> Split(string const & str_, char const * sep)
{
  string str = str_.c_str();
  size_t sep_len = ::strlen(sep);

  vector<string> ret;
  for (size_t i = str.find(sep); i != str.npos; i = str.find(sep))
  {
    ret.push_back(str.substr(0, i));
    str = str.substr(i + sep_len, str.npos);
  }
  if (str.length() > 0)
    ret.push_back(str);
  return ret;
}

/// 
/// This function converts string to wstring.
/// 
wstring ToWStr(string const& x, UINT code_page )
{
  // Allocate the appropriate space
  int sizeRequired = MultiByteToWideChar(code_page, 0, x.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
  wchar_t * ach = new wchar_t[sizeRequired + 1];

  // Convert it
  MultiByteToWideChar(code_page, 0, x.c_str(), -1, ach, sizeRequired);

  // Put it into the return value
  wstring ret(ach);

  // Clean up
  delete[] ach;

  // Return the new string
  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  LPWSTR wszPath = NULL;
  HRESULT hr;
  wstring strPath;
  hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData , KF_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, &wszPath);

  if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
    strPath = wszPath; 
    strPath += L"\\Mozilla\\Firefox";

    wstring profileFilePath = strPath + L"\\profiles.ini";
    wstring strCurrentProfile =  ReadINIFileAndGetFirefoxProfilePath(profileFilePath);
    wstring prefsPath = strPath + L"\\" + strCurrentProfile + L"\\prefs.js";

    wstring strProxy = ReadProxyFromFile(prefsPath);
    if (strProxy.length()>0)
    {
      wcout << "Proxy is " <<strProxy <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}

wstring ReadINIFileAndGetFirefoxProfilePath( wstring &profileFilePath ) 
{
  // reading each section from ini file
  LPWSTR pSecNames= new WCHAR[1024];
  int nSectionNum = 1;
  wstring strAllSectionNames;

  DWORD retVal = GetPrivateProfileSectionNames(pSecNames,1024,profileFilePath.c_str());

  if (retVal)
  {
    for (unsigned int i =0; i < retVal; i++)
    {
      if (pSecNames[i] == NULL)
      {
        strAllSectionNames += L"_";
      }
      else
      {
        strAllSectionNames += pSecNames[i];
      }
    }
  delete pSecNames;

  string sectionNames = ToString(strAllSectionNames.c_str(),CP_UTF8);
  vector <string> sectionNamesVector = Split(sectionNames.c_str(),"_");

  wstring strSectionName;
  for ( int it = 0 ; it < sectionNamesVector.size(); it++ )
  {
    strSectionName = ToWStr(sectionNamesVector.at(it),CP_UTF8);
    wcout << nSectionNum << ". Section name: " << strSectionName;
    LPWSTR pProfile= new WCHAR[1024];
    DWORD active = GetPrivateProfileString(strSectionName.c_str(),L"Default",NULL,pProfile,MAX,profileFilePath.c_str());
    if(active)
    {
      GetPrivateProfileString(strSectionName.c_str(),L"Path",NULL,(LPWSTR)pProfile,MAX,profileFilePath.c_str());
      wstring strPath = pProfile;
      delete pProfile;
      return strPath;
    }
    delete pProfile;
    nSectionNum++;
  }
 }
}


wstring ReadProxyFromFile(wstring fileName)
{
  wstring proxyType;
  wstring proxyHttp;
  wstring httpPort;
  wstring noProxiesOn;
  wstring autoconfigUrl;
  wstring proxySettings; 
  wstring field;
  int nProxyType;

  wifstream myfile;
  wstring strLine;
  size_t pos;

  myfile.open (fileName.c_str());
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
      getline(myfile,strLine);
      if (!strLine.find(L"user_pref"))
      {
        pos = strLine.find_first_of(L", ");
        field = strLine.substr(11,pos-12);

        if (field == L"network.proxy.type")
        {
          proxyType  = ParseAndGetProxyDetails(strLine, field);
          nProxyType = _wtoi(proxyType.c_str());
        }
        if (field == L"network.proxy.http")
        {
          proxyHttp  = ParseAndGetProxyDetails(strLine, field);
        }
        if (field == L"network.proxy.http_port")
        {
          httpPort  = ParseAndGetProxyDetails(strLine, field);
        }
        if (field == L"network.proxy.autoconfig_url")
        {
          autoconfigUrl  = ParseAndGetProxyDetails(strLine, field);
        }
        if (field == L"network.proxy.no_proxies_on")
        {
          noProxiesOn  = ParseAndGetProxyDetails(strLine, field);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  myfile.close();

  switch (nProxyType)
  {
  case 0: // no proxy
    proxySettings = L"FF:";
    break;
  case 1: // manual proxy
    proxySettings = L"FF:PXY:"+proxyHttp+L":"+httpPort;
    break;
  case 2: //autoconfig_url
    proxySettings = L"FF:URL:"+autoconfigUrl;
    break;
  case 4: // auto proxy
    proxySettings = L"FF:";
    break;
  default: // system proxy
    proxySettings = L"FF::";
    break;
  }

  return proxySettings;
}

wstring ParseAndGetProxyDetails (wstring strLine, wstring field)
{
  size_t position;
  wstring proxyDetail;
  position = strLine.find(field);
  if (position != string::npos)
  {
    proxyDetail = strLine.substr(position);
    position = proxyDetail.find_first_of(L",");
    proxyDetail = proxyDetail.substr(position+1);
    position = proxyDetail.find_first_of(L");");
    proxyDetail = proxyDetail.substr(0,position);
  }
  return proxyDetail;
}
```